# How Do I use a node.js module with Next.js?

Tags: npm, next.js

Do I need to use express with next.js?

Im trying to add this code into a next.js application. ( from npm module example code: pdf2json )

```
let fs = require('fs');
var PDFParser = require("pdf2json");
let pdfParser = new PDFParser(this,1);

pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => 
   console.error(errData.parserError) );
pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
fs.writeFile("./sometxt.txt", pdfParser.getRawTextContent());
pdfParser.loadPDF("./page1.pdf");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can require it conditionally by testing if it is the server:

```
static async getInitialProps({isServer}){
 var fs;
 if(isServer){
  fs=require('fs');
  //and do what ever you want
 }
}
```

and dot not forgot to tell webpack to do not send the module to the client side by changing package.json like so:

```
  "browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
```

unless it can produce errors.

Comment: Can I add more than one argument to get initial props?

Answer (score 0):

The thing that's probably biting you is that most of your code must work on both the client and the server. You can write server-only code by creating a `getInitialProps()` method and checking to see if it's passed in a `opts.req` - if so, you know the code is running server-side and you can hit the filesystem:

```
import React from 'react'

const doServerSideStuff = () => {
    let fs = require('fs');
    var PDFParser = require("pdf2json");
    let pdfParser = new PDFParser(this,1);

    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => 
       console.error(errData.parserError) );
    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
    fs.writeFile("./sometxt.txt", pdfParser.getRawTextContent());
    pdfParser.loadPDF("./page1.pdf");
}

export default class extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps ({ req }) {
    if (req) {
      doServerSideStuff();
    }
    return {};
  }
  render () {
    return <div> Hello World </div>
  }
}
```

This isn't really a complete example yet, you should really make `doServerSideStuff()` async (or return a promise) and then await it in `getInitialProps`, and eventually return props that represent the result of the parsing & saving. Also, handle `fs.writeFile` errors. But, hopefully it's enough to get you going in the right direction.

See [the docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle) for some more info on this.

Or you could just use Express like you suggested. There is a [good tutorial](https://learnnextjs.com/basics/server-side-support-for-clean-urls) and [example code](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/v3-beta/examples/custom-server-express) that should help you get started if you decide to go that route.