# Can't use 'fs' in getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to get the contents of a parsed file inside `getInitialProps` when my view loads, the problem is that it tells me that `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'` and I don't understand why - according to the documentation, [it enables server-side rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps).

My API route:

```
import parseCommands, { ICommands } from "../../modules/parser/json";

export const getCommands = (): ICommands => {
    const commands = parseCommands("data.json");

    return commands;
};
```

My react view:

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import { getCommands } from "../../pages/api/commands";
import { ICommands } from "../../modules/parser/json";
import styles from "./commands.module.scss";

type Props = {
    commands: ICommands;
};

const Commands:NextPage<Props> = ({ commands }) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            {commands}
        </div>
    );
};

Commands.getInitialProps = async () => {
    const commands:ICommands = await getCommands();

    return {
        commands
    };
};

export default Commands;
```

My file trying to import the module 'fs':

```
import fs from "fs";

[...]

const parseCommands = (path: string): ICommands => {
    const file:string = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8");
    const json:any = JSON.parse(file);

    const commands:ICommands = parseData(json);

    return commands;
};

export default parseCommands;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wait `fs` in the frontend, not possible, SSR knows as server-side rendering, not server-side operation, that's why you can't perform any server-side things in react or next

Comment: @Nisharg Shah actually, in Next.js you can perform server side rendering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I use a node.js module with Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983810/how-do-i-use-a-node-js-module-with-next-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your next.js version - [Update for modern Next.js (9.4+)](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7755)

You may also need to create a next.config.js file with the following content to get the client bundle to build:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
    if (!isServer) {
      config.node = {
        fs: 'empty'
      }
    }

    return config
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getInitialProps` runs on both the server and client side, so it is not possible to use `fs` without branching. Use `getServerSideProps` instead.

You can bodge out the module with Or's answer, but it's just working around the problem.

Alternatively, you can branch in `getInitialProps` to determine if we're on the server at code execution. You should not use `readFileSync` in web server code.

```
export const getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  if (res === undefined) {
    return { commands: [] }
  }

  const fs = await import('fs')
  const readFile = fs.promises.readFile;
  return { commands: await readFile(...) }
}
```